# Empty body when disabling Split On functionality in Azure Logic App with Blob Storage Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

In my use case I'm uploading images to the Azure Blob Storage and from there, I want to copy them over to our legacy FTP site. Doing this file per file is giving issues (2000 files at a time..) since it establishes and closes FTP connections very rapidly and thus overloads the FTP server.

I want the Logic App to connect once and then create the files for how many blobs it pulled. This seems doable since all I would have to do is not have the Split On functionality enabled, however, when I do this, the entire body is empty and all I get is headers. I'm lost at this point.

Since I have no rep yet, here's a direct link to the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROuGg.png

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Logic App runs once with an empty body and then runs again with the body you'd expect. This makes the built-in "Run" option completely worthless but at least it does what it says it does.